# Defaults set from UI in Users View are not working Odoo

Tags: user-interface, default, odoo-10, formview

I set defaults to groups in Users form and save them. The saved defaults appear in Settings->Actions->User-defined defaults but they do not show when I try to create a new user.

Comment: Can you please Add more information to your question?

Comment: In the users view, when you click create, we can add defaults from the view. Debug icon-> Set defaults. When I save a default, like fieldName = defaultValue and hit save. This gets saved in the Settings->Action->User-defined defaults, but when I try to create another user, the defaults do not appear. @VikiChavada

Comment: Which field you are trying to set as default?

Comment: I was trying on the fields that have dropdown. To be precise on Sales field.

Comment: This is the solution I was suggested in odoo forum, still doesn't work for me but might help you understand the question better. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/defaults-set-from-ui-in-users-view-are-not-working-124108